# Why is click event not working on MacOS Safari?

Tags: jquery, safari, click

I have this jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // When the page is loading show the #preloader element 
    $("#preloader").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#page-container").fadeIn("slow");
    // When an article with article grid is clicked, display the loader
    $("a").on("touchstart click", function() { 
        $("#preloader").fadeIn("slow"); 
        });
});
```

How it should work:

1. Page loads and immediately shows the #preloader element. As soon as the page is loaded, the #preloader element fades out and the #page-container fades in.
2. Then, when you click on a link, the #preloader element fades in while the browser loads the next page. Back to step 1.

So there is a seamless transition between page loads.

This works great on Firefox and Chrome. But on Safari and all iOS browsers, the click event in step 2 isn't working. The #preloader element doesn't fade in before the new page loads.

I tried adding preventDefault which got the #preloader element to fade in, but then the browser never redirected to the new page.

Any ideas?

Comment: are the `<a>` elements clicked part of a dynamically injected content?

Comment: @LorenzoS No, they are part of the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. Here is what I ended up using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // When the page is loading show the #preloader element 
    $("#preloader").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#page-container").fadeIn("slow");
    // When an link is clicked, display the loader
    $("a").on("touchstart click", function() { 
        event.preventDefault();
        newLocation = this.href;
        $("#preloader").fadeIn("slow", newpage); 
    });
    function newpage() {
        window.location = newLocation;
    }
});
```